# Calling didSelectRow programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

As the titles says, is there any way to call the didSelectrow in a pickerview? Im working on my first "big" project (currency converter) and this is a problem that i can't seem to figure out. This is a bit of the code taken from the .m file:

```
//Toggle reverse on/off
- (IBAction)Reverse:(id)sender {
    reverse = (reverse+1)%2;
    NSString *tmpstring = string1;
    string1 = string2;
    string2 = tmpstring;

    if (!reverse) {
        [Picker1 selectRow:row2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [Picker1 selectRow:row1 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
        Text1.text = [Datarray objectAtIndex:row2];
    } else {
        [Picker1 selectRow:row1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [Picker1 selectRow:row2 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
          Text1.text = [Datarray objectAtIndex:row1];
    }
    tmpstring = nil;
    [self Editingdidend:self];
    NSLog(@"%d",reverse);
    //[call didSelectRow here]
}

-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    XMLparse *parse = [[XMLparse alloc]init];
    if (component == 0) {
    Text1.text = [Datarray objectAtIndex:row];
        string1 = [Datarray objectAtIndex:row];
        row1 = row;
        [parse setHowmuchmoney:[Inputter.text floatValue]];
        [parse setValutanamn1:string1];
        [parse setValutanamn2:string2];
        [parse loadDataFromXML];
        Output.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [parse convertionrate]];
    } else {
        string2 = [Datarray objectAtIndex:row];
        row2 = row;
        [parse setHowmuchmoney:[Inputter.text floatValue]];
        [parse setValutanamn1:string1];
        [parse setValutanamn2:string2];
        [parse loadDataFromXML];
        Output.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [parse convertionrate]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to call `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` from your `Reverse:` method?

Comment: well, it's hard to explain and i don't even know myself really. But, I think it's because otherwise the row1 and row2 won't refresh afterwards and it will couse problem sometimes if i call didselctrow  aprogrammatlicly.

Comment: You should take much of the code from your `didSelectRow` method and put it in a new method. Then both your `Reverse:` and `didSelectRow` methods can call this new method.

Comment: yh, but the only reason why i want to call it, is because i want row1 = row and row2 = row to refresh. I cannot get that from outside the function;

Comment: Edit found out i could do this in the reverse method: row1 = [Picker1 selectedRowInComponent:0];